# SignalR latest version .NET Framework 4

Tags: .net, signalr

SignalR 2 is only supported on .NET Famework 4.5

What's the latest SignalR version for .NET Framework 4

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place for a question like this. Perhaps you could try the signalr room: http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases we can see the last release for 1.x is 1.2.2.